# Entity Framework POCO long-term change tracking

Tags: c#, wpf, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using .NET entity framework 4.1 with code-first approach to effectively solve the following problem, here simplified.

- There's a database table with tens of thousands of entries.
- Several users of my program need to be able to

  - View the (entire) table in a GridRow, which implied that the entire Table has to be downloaded.
  - Modify values of any random row, changes are frequent but need not be persisted immediately. It's expected that different users will modify different rows, but this is not always true. Some loss of changes is permitted, as users will most likely update same rows to same values.
  - On occasion add new rows.

Sounds simple enough. My initial approach was to use a long-running `DbContext` instance. This one `DbContext` was supposed to track changes to the entities, so that when `SaveChanges()` is called, most of the legwork is done automatically. However many have pointed out that this is not an **optimal solution in the long run**, notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392). I'm still not sure if I understand the reasons, and I don't see what a unit-of-work is in my scenario either. The user chooses herself when to persist changes, and let's say that client always wins for simplicity. It's also important to note that objects that have not been touched don't overwrite any data in the database.

Another approach would be to track changes manually or use objects that track changes for me, however I'm not too familiar with such techniques, and I would welcome a nudge in the right direction.

What's the correct way to solve this problem?

I understand that this question is a bit wishy-washy, but think of it as more fundamental. I lack fundamental understanding about how to solve this class of problems. It seems to me that long living `DbContext` is the right way, but knowledgeable people tell me otherwise, which leads me to confusion and imprecise questions.

**EDIT1**
Another point of confusion is the existance of `Local` property on the `DbSet<>` object. It invites me to use a long running context, as another user has posted [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx).

Comment: What kind of application are you building? Is it web or windows app?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka It's a WPF application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with long running context is that it doesn't refresh data - I more discussed problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392). So if your user opens the list and modify data half an hour she doesn't know about changes. But in case of WPF if your business action is:

- Open the list
- Do as many actions as you want
- Trigger saving changes

Then this whole is unit of work and you can use single context instance for that. If you have scenario where last edit wins you should not have problems with this until somebody else deletes record which current user edits. Additionally after saving or cancelling changes you should dispose current context and load data again - this will ensure that you really have fresh data for next unit of work.

Context offers some features to refresh data but it only refreshes data previously loaded (without relations) so for example new unsaved records will be still included.

Perhaps you can also read about MS Sync framework and local data cache.

Comment: Actually you have already provided me with means to refresh context which seems to work fine in my scenario. But I'd rather do it cleanly as you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: could you weigh in on the discussion in the answer below? I would really appreciate some insight into what's really happening. I don't know why I'm so sure, and that makes me question everything. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your users could have a copy (cached) of the data for an indefinate period of time.  The longer the users are using cached data the greater the odds that they could become disconnected from the database connection in DbContext.  My guess is EF doesn't handle this well and you probably want to deal with that.  (e.g. *occaisionally connected* architecture).  I would expect implementing that may solve many of your issues.

Comment: I don't think you are right on this one. In fact it's a myth of sorts. Any query through DbContext can have a connection failure, and retry logic is always needed to verify that this didn't happen. But it *will* get a new connection if you retry your operation.

Comment: Myth? Just tried it, created a context, got a row, caused SQL server to disconnect and got an exception in SaveChanges.

Comment: And what happens if you do SaveChanges() again?

Comment: Well, you are supposed to handle that exception. The exception is just a dud connection. Next time you do SaveChanges(), the context would have magicked up a new one. This is to the best of my understanding of recommended guidelines.

Comment: If that is indeed true, and "best of [your] undestanding" doesn't mean you are guessing; please post your source.

Otherwise, this is a bit silly.  EntityException is the only exception throw--which offers no good way to decide if the exception was indeed due to a disconnection and whether to decide if "retrying" wouldn't just send the application into an endless loop.

Comment: My source is "Transient Fault Handling Framework for SQL Azure" (1) and associated documentation, and the reason I call it myth, is because I've seen it mentioned and debunked on stackoverflow. From the (1) source code, it's apparent that the EntityException is expected to have a SqlException as InnerException, which has a Number property. Errors No. 40501, 10053 and 10054 seem to indicate faulty connection. It's expected of developers to retry operation on those errors, but they happen so seldom that nobody bothers. Although some errors like "server busy" happen more frequently on Azure.

Comment: Ehm, I've just run a few tests. It seems to work fine, although for some reason I generated error No. 121, instead of those mentioned in the Transient Fault Handling Framework. Oh well, best to put it in... :)

Comment: Hmm, wasn't aware we switched to SQL Azure; but that does bring up an excellent point.  At best your recomendation is fragile.  Expects an inner exception of specific type with properties of specific values.  At worst it couples my code to a specific type of database. One of the reasons for using EF is to decouple an application from the database more.  I really doubt as more databases are supported by EF that disconnections in those will have inner exceptions of type SqlClient.SqlException...

Comment: My "point" was that SaveChanges() can faulter, and it's expected of the developer to retry that operation. I'm going to pose the question, Ladislav will settle it for us. :)